# Override error with jOOQ 3.9 update

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Since I've updated jOOQ to 3.9.0 version and now with 3.9.1 version, I have the following error message in all the generated "Table" classes for the "rename" method:

Error java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

```
/**
* Rename this table
*/
@Override
public CompanyTable rename(String name) {
    return new CompanyTable(name, null);
}
```

Is it the normal behavior ? Is there something to do to automatically remove the Override annotation of those "rename" methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this is that you're using jOOQ 3.9.x for your code generation but 3.8.x (or a previous version) for compilation.

Be sure to check your classpath for any duplicate references of the jOOQ library with potentially conflicting versions.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right, it was because of the modelmapper jooq extension dependency...